# Giving alias in JOIN command in sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, join, alias, sqldatasource

I am using `JOIN` command to connect two tables in SqlDataSource.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CS %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT UserName as UN, AboutMe, WebPage, Email FROM Users JOIN ProfileImages ON ProfileImages.UserName = Users.UN WHERE (UN = @UserName)" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In MS SQL Server Management Studio this command is ok. But in the SqlDataSource it return errors - *Invalid column name 'UN'*, *Ambiguous column name 'UserName'*

How do I alias this command right in SqlDataSource to not return these errors?

Comment: ON ProfileImages.UserName = Users.UserName... you can't use alias in the join criteria like you tried..

Comment: This isn't ok on Management studio, you can't use a column alias on the join condition, nor in the where (it can be use in the `ORDER BY`, though)

Comment: The part `SELECT UserName AS UN` was ok in Managemente Studion, sorry. I fixed that to `ProfileImages.UserName = Users.UserName`, but it still return error  **Ambiguous column name 'UserName'**

Comment: you can't use alias in your joins or where clause, only order by and if you aren't sure, just don't use them in your logic, only for column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is a bit wrong
You used alias i a wrong way

First:
You can use alias in the following sections:

- Fields. Example Username as UN
- Tables names: UserTable as US
- In the order by section example: Order BY UN Desc

This because the sql runs the query operations in the following sequence:

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

So because the `FROM` clause runs first the sql doesn't know about the alias in the `SELECT` clause

Take a look on a correct query

```
SELECT 
    UserName as UN,
    AboutMe,
    WebPage,
    Email 
FROM Users 
JOIN ProfileImages ON ProfileImages.UserName = Users.UserName 
WHERE (Users.UserName = @UserName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at SQL, but if both ProfileImages and Users contain the column 'UserName', then in your select columns you need to specify the table from which the UserName is pulled.  So something like:

```
SELECT Users.UserName as UN, Users.AboutMe, Users.WebPage, Users.Email 
FROM Users
JOIN ProfileImages ON ProfileImages.UserName = Users.UserName 
WHERE (Users.UserName = @UserName)
```

Comment: With this, you get rid of the *Ambiguous column name 'UserName'*, but you are still using a column alias on the `JOIN` condition and in the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the column alias in the where clause.

```
    SELECT UserName as UN, AboutMe, WebPage, Email 
    FROM Users usersAlias JOIN ProfileImages piAlias ON piAlias.UserName = usersAlias.UserName 
WHERE (usersAlias.UserName = @UserName)
```

It makes sense when you look at the order of execution:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Since the order of execution is:
These phases and their orders are given as follows:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
   10 ORDER BY
10. TOP

When these are being processed (the "from" (#1) and "on" (#2) and "where" (#4))..they have no knowledge about the "select" (#8) (aka, the alias name for UN), the column alias in the select clause cannot be used in the WHERE and FROM (and ON) clauses.